# Fastify reload browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, frameworks, fastify

In Fastify framework is there anyway to reflesh the browser when changes happen on save.
In Express we have `npm livereload` as a middleware to listen to backend changes in Express. Are there any similar functions in Fastify or do I have to write my own registered plugin to automatically reflesh the browser on backend changes?

Answer (score 2):

The `livereload` package that you mentioned is a general-purpose tool that works with Fastify as well. I was able to make it run with the following packages:

- [typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript) Running `tsc -w -outdir dist/` to watch the `.ts` files and transpile them into `.js` files
- [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) Running `nodemon -r dotenv/config dist/server.js` to watch the `.js` files and restart the web server
- [livereload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload) Running `livereload ./dist/ -w 500` so that the browser refreshes once the server restarted
- [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) To tie it all together in the `package.json`

  ```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node -r dotenv/config dist/server.js",
    "dev:tsc": "tsc -w -outdir dist/",
    "dev:watch": "nodemon -r dotenv/config dist/server.js",
    "dev:livereload": "livereload ./dist/ -w 500",
    "dev": "concurrently -k -p \"[{name}]\" -n \"TypeScript,App,LiveReload\" -c \"yellow.bold,cyan.bold,green.bold\" \"yarn dev:tsc\" \"yarn dev:watch\" \"yarn dev:livereload\" "
  },
  ```

> Note that you need to include the following `<script>` tag in your `.html` files to make livereload work
>
> ```
> <script>
>     document.write(
>       '<script src="http://' +
>         (location.host || "localhost").split(":")[0] +
>         ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' +
>         "script>"
>     );
> </script>
> ```

This was enough to make my small Fastify project run, your milage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is the `fastify-cli` module for that:
https://github.com/fastify/fastify-cli

it has the `--watch` option that you can use to live reload your backend on file changes.

In your `package.json` add this script:

```
 "dev": "fastify start -l info --watch --pretty-logs app.js",
```

Note that app.js must expose this interface:

```
module.exports = function (fastify, ops, next) {
  next()
}
```

Comment: It doesn't refresh the browser only reloads the server. I need something that can refresh the browser aswell.